# does the compiler consider actual types in error handling in java

Tags: java, error-handling, try-catch, throwable

why does this work

```
class blah{
    public void someMethod(){
        try{
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
        catch(Throwable t){
            System.out.println("Caught!");
            throw t;
        }
    }
}
```

it seems like the compiler some how see the actual type of t

Answer (score 0):

It works because `NullPointerException` is an instance of `Throwable`. The catch clause catches all instances of the declared type.

Comment: You can't normally `throw` a `Throwable` (i.e. `t`) without catching it (`catch`) or declaring it (`throws Throwable`), since it is neither a `RuntimeException` or an `Error`.

Comment: I never said you can do so.

Comment: The question is why `throw t` doesn't fail to compile, given that it is *declared* to be of type `Throwable`, which is not one of the two unchecked types (`RuntimeException` and `Error`).

Comment: Because `Throwable` is the superclass of them.

Comment: But `Throwable` itself is a *checked* type, so question is "why does this work", i.e. why does `throw t` not complain that the checked `Throwable` is not caught or declared? You are not answering that at all.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're actually saying, since `NullPointerException`, being an instance of `RuntimeException`, doesn't need to be caught or declared, the question isn't why that part works. The question is (paraphrased): *Why does this work? It seems like the compiler some how see the actual type of `t`, i.e. that `t` is not a `Throwable` but a `NullPointerException`, so throwing `t` is ok, because otherwise throwing a `Throwable` would be a compile error.*

Comment: Im not quite sure what the point of the question is, I thought it is about the `catch(Throwable t)` clause. That works because `NullPointerException` is an instance of `Throwable`.

Comment: It's about the `throw t` statement, which will fail to compile before Java 7, because `Throwable` (the declared type of `t`) is a **checked** type.

Comment: Ah, well, it would have been helpful if the first post would have said so.

Comment: If by "first post" you mean my first comment, then I did specifically mention `throw` of `t`.

Comment: No, I meant the person who asked that question.

Answer (score 0):

That code will fail to compile before Java 7.

From the [Java SE 7 Features and Enhancements](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jdk7-relnotes-418459.html), section [Catching Multiple Exception Types and Rethrowing Exceptions with Improved Type Checking](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/catch-multiple.html):

> **Rethrowing Exceptions with More Inclusive Type Checking**
>
> The Java SE 7 compiler performs more precise analysis of rethrown exceptions than earlier releases of Java SE. This enables you to specify more specific exception types in the `throws` clause of a method declaration.
>
> Consider the following example:
>
> ```
> static class FirstException extends Exception { }
> static class SecondException extends Exception { }
>
> public void rethrowException(String exceptionName) throws Exception {
>   try {
>     if (exceptionName.equals("First")) {
>       throw new FirstException();
>     } else {
>       throw new SecondException();
>     }
>   } catch (Exception e) {
>     throw e;
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> This examples's `try` block could throw either `FirstException` or `SecondException`. Suppose you want to specify these exception types in the `throws` clause of the `rethrowException` method declaration. In releases prior to Java SE 7, you cannot do so. Because the exception parameter of the `catch` clause, `e`, is type `Exception`, and the catch block rethrows the exception parameter `e`, you can only specify the exception type `Exception` in the `throws` clause of the `rethrowException` method declaration.
>
> However, in Java SE 7, you can specify the exception types `FirstException` and `SecondException` in the `throws` clause in the `rethrowException` method declaration. The Java SE 7 compiler can determine that the exception thrown by the statement `throw e` must have come from the `try` block, and the only exceptions thrown by the `try` block can be `FirstException` and `SecondException`. Even though the exception parameter of the `catch` clause, `e`, is type `Exception`, the compiler can determine that it is an instance of either `FirstException` or `SecondException`:
>
> ```
> public void rethrowException(String exceptionName)
> throws FirstException, SecondException {
>   try {
>     // ...
>   }
>   catch (Exception e) {
>     throw e;
>   }
> }
> ```

Answer (score -1):

NullPointerException is a child of Excepsion. Exception is a child of Throwable. So thats should work becouse of Polymorphism.

Comment: You can't normally `throw` a `Throwable` (i.e. `t`) without catching it (`catch`) or declaring it (`throws Throwable`), since it is neither a `RuntimeException` or an `Error`.